# How to select paragraphs with no dot at the end and remove - with jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following paragraphs:

```
<p>This is a first paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a second</p>
<p>A third paragraph is here.</p>
<p>And a fourth</p>
```

The second and fourth paragraphs don't have a full stop at the end of the sentence. Is there a way to select these paragraphs and then remove them with jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('p').each(function() {
   var par = $(this), text = par.text();
   if (text.charAt(text.length-1) !== '.') {
      par.remove();
   }
});
```

of course it requires no extra spaces (or other characters) between the dot and the end of the paragraph: in that case a regular expression check instead of `charAt()` could be a better choice

Comment: Just a thought, shouldnt it be more efficient to just substring the last character instead to use a regex?

Comment: Awesome solution +1 I'd put a trim but thats me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if(this.innerHTML[this.innerHTML.length - 1] != '.')
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is this:
    `<p>.*?(?<!\.\s*)</p>`

This does a negative lookbehind to assert that the paragraph does not end with a dot.

I added a `\s*` to allow for space after a period.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `each`:

```
$("p").filter(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();

    return text.charAt(text.length - 1) != ".";
}).remove();
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NS5hU/).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has some pretty convenient selectors for this. Try:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    $(this + ':not(:contains(.))').remove();
});
```

[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TDbkh/2/)

Comment: Just realized if you have larger paragraphs with multiple sentences this wouldn't work as it matches anything containing a period anywhere. F. Calderan's answer works well for bigger paragraphs.